# List view adapter in android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I have a Base Adapter and there are three views in the getView() of the base adapter. 2 textviews and one delete button.

the first text view is the name of the product, the second textview is the counter (how many products purchased kind off shopping cart) and third is the delete button.

say, eg., shirts 2 delete_button
          spoons 1 delete_button
          utencils 3 delete_button.

Now, the problem is when I click the first delete button, the value of the last textview gets decremented.

Following is my code.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_billing_row_layout, parent, false);

        txt_product_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_product_name);
        txt_count = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_count);

        btn_delete = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_prodcut);

        btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.i("Test", "******** position delete: " + position);



                if(array_list_products.get(position).getCounter() > 0) {


                    if(array_list_products.get(position).getCounter() != 1) {

                        array_list_products.get(position).setCounter(array_list_products.get(position).getCounter() - 1);

                        txt_count.setText("");
                        txt_count.setText("" + (array_list_products.get(position).getCounter() - 1));

                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

I think the problem is the text view is at the last position and the I am clicking on the delete button which is at the first position and hence the value of the last text view is decrementing.

Comment: what is the desired behaviour ?

Comment: When I click the first delete button, the value of the counter should decrement to 1. It is decrementing the value but at the time of displaying, it is displaying in the last counter textview not in the first counter text view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// List view recycle the view so set tag to delete button so that we get the clicked position


   @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_billing_row_layout, parent, false);

        holder.txt_product_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_view_product_name);
        holder.txt_count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_count);

        holder.btn_delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_prodcut);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // initialize your text and data
     holder.txt_count.setText("Hello");

     holder.btn_delete.setTag(position);

     holder.btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int clickedPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();

            if(array_list_products.get(clickedPosition).getCounter() > 0) {
                 if(array_list_products.get(clickedPosition).getCounter() != 1) {
                     array_list_products.get(clickedPosition).setCounter(array_list_products.get(clickedPosition).getCounter() - 1);

                        holder.txt_count.setText("");
                        holder.txt_count.setText("" + (array_list_products.get(clickedPosition).getCounter() - 1));

                 }
            }

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_product_name;
    TextView txt_count;
    Button  btn_delete;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what you can try is setting the tag of position on the button

```
   btn_delete.setTag(position);
btn_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Log.i("Test", "******** position delete: " + position);


                int pos=(int)arg0.getTag();
                if(array_list_products.get(pos).getCounter() > 0) {


                    if(array_list_products.get(pos).getCounter() != 1) {

                        array_list_products.get(position).setCounter(array_list_products.get(pos).getCounter() - 1);

                        txt_count.setText("");
                        txt_count.setText("" + (array_list_products.get(pos).getCounter() - 1));

                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried your way of putting the tag. But when I put btn_delete.setTag(position), the position is the last position of the view rendered.

Comment: use holder.btn_delete.setTag(position) instead of
 
btn_delete.setTag(position)

Answer (score 0):

In the setOnClickListener(),

- don't call any txt_count.setText()
- do array_list_products.get(position).setCounter( array_list_products.get(position).getCounter() - 1))
  //you need to implement setCounter() in your product class
- call notifyDataSetInvalidated()

In the getView(),

- call txt_count.setText( array_list_products.get(position) )